# Proxy Switchy Omega extension on Chrome: How to set up with OpenVPN

Tags: google-chrome, vpn, proxy, openvpn

I use OpenVPN to connect to my university account from home (Win 10 laptop). I was thinking of using [Proxy Switchy](https://github.com/FelisCatus/SwitchyOmega/wiki/FAQ) as a Chrome extension to automate this process for certain websites.

I'm getting stuck at configuring Proxy Switchy. If I want it to use OpenVPN what do I put as the config settings under server and port? I've added a screenshot below. Am I doing this wrong somehow?

[image]